# Why is mysql (all the sudden) translating 127.0.0.1 to localhost internally?

Tags: mysql, tcp

I have a strange issue with mysql. I want to connect to the database using the mysql client, and since I want to force connection via TCP I do this:

```
$ mysql --protocol=TCP -uroot -p -h127.0.0.1
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

As you can see, the connection fails, because there is no root access defined for 'root'@'localhost'. This is true - I did not GRANT any privileges to this hostname. However I did specify the root account with full privileges for 'root'@'127.0.0.1'.

I was able to connect to the database in the past with the above mentioned command. However, now it fails. I am not sure if a system update happened in between but something must have changed.

Does anyone have a solution? I would rather not stop the database server for that if possible.

Some more background info. This is running the mysql flavor percona server 5.6 on an ubuntu 14.04 LTE box with everything up to date.

Comment: Try just :`mysql -u root -p`

Comment: wow! It woks. But why?

Comment: This seems to answer your question of 'why', Luksch:  http://razorsql.com/docs/mysql_connection_troubleshooting.html